# numbers raised to logarithmic expressions

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I'm currently 11th grader in secondary school and we are learning logarithms. I think I know them quite well but I'm stuck on this exercise:

> Evaluate $2^x - 10^y$, where $x=1/log_6(2)$ and $y=2/log_2(10)$.

When I plug the values in the calculator I get an answer of 10. But can someone show me the algorithm on how to calculate this? Because I'm unable to get the answer by myself (Sorry if some terms are not on point, I'm not a native English speaker.)

Comment: where is the equation?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner there is no equation

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner the exercise asks to calculate the value of this expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $$\displaystyle x= \frac{1}{\log_{6}(2)} = \log_{2}(6)$$ and $$\displaystyle y = \frac{2}{\log_{2}(10)} = 2\log_{10}(2) = \log_{10}(2)^2 = \log_{10}(4)$$

Now $$2^x-10^y = 2^{\log_{2}(6)} -10^{\log_{10}(4)} = 6-4=2$$

Above we have used the formula $$\displaystyle \bullet\; \log_{a}(b)\times \log_{b}(a) =1$$ and $$\displaystyle \bullet\; n\times \log_{e}(m) = \log_{e}(m)^n$$

and  $$\displaystyle \bullet\; a^{\log_{a}(x)} = x$$

Comment: Thank you very much! you made everything perfectly understandable!